# Can we use SMO to take backup of database located at hosting server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, hosting, backup, smo

I followed the examples from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163409.aspx

I am creating a utility that creates backup of databases (local or remote).
I was able to create backup of databases located at my local server. But when I do so for databases located at host server I get following error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError`: Cannot open backup device 'D:\Brij\Docs\MyDb.bak'. `Operating system error 21(The device is not ready.)`.

Looks like `SMO` creates the backup file where the server is located, and hence it is not finding the path. Am I correct ? How could I take backup of a database from a host server and get the backup file in my local machine ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334238/sql-server-smo-take-back-up-locally-from-remote-server
As per this, can't do it.

Comment: You can ask your hoster to backup it for you and then you can download it via FTP. That's my suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Backup paths are always relative to the server. You can backup to UNC (which I do personally, even if it's a local UNC) or, if you're on a sufficiently recent build of SQL 2012, Azure blob storage (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148.aspx).